# (R) How can I recode multiple columns and make them as new columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have data like this

```
> data

satface1         satface2               satface3         satface 4 ... satface10
Agree            Disagree               Neutral
Disagree         Strongly Disagree      Strongly Agree
Agree            Disagree               Agree
Neutral          Agree                  Neutral
Strongly Agree   Neutral                Disagree
```

and I want to recode

```
Strongly Disagree = 1, Disagree = 2, Neutral = 3, Agree = 4, Disagree = 5
```

and make them as new columns (name satface1_re, satface2_re....) How can I do that?

```
> data

satface1         satface2               satface3       (satface4...10)  satface1_re satface2_re satface3_re
Agree            Disagree               Neutral                          4           2           3 
Disagree         Strongly Disagree      Strongly Agree                   2           1           5
Agree            Disagree               Agree                            4           2           4
Neutral          Agree                  Neutral                          3           4           3
Strongly Agree   Neutral                Disagree                         5           3           2
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is to recode with `factor`.  Specify the `levels` in the order required, and coerce to `numeric` with `as.integer` in `across` and add new column by altering the `.names`

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
lvls <- c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree") 
data1 <- data %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with('satface'),
        ~ as.integer(factor(., levels = lvls)), .names = "{col}_re"))
```

---

Or using `recode` with a named `vector`

```
data %>% 
   mutate(across(starts_with('satface'),
     ~ recode(., !!! setNames(1:5, lvls)), .names = "{col}_re"))
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(satface1 = c("Agree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Neutral", 
"Strongly Agree"), satface2 = c("Disagree", "Strongly Disagree", 
"Disagree", "Agree", "Neutral"), satface3 = c("Neutral", "Strongly Agree", 
"Agree", "Neutral", "Disagree")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I was trying to play with it, and I did `recode(data, "Agree" = 1)` for a short trial, but I was getting errors.

Comment: @DanielJachetta you can try the updated code.  In your code, `recode` is applied to the whole data.  where I applied on each column i..e vector

Comment: @DanielJachetta or use `data %>% mutate(across(starts_with('satface'), ~ recode(., `Strongly Disagree` = 1, Disagree = 2, Neutral = 3)))`